# How to get TextEdit value to Cell in GridView in Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have TextEdit field and GridView in the Form, now I want to get that value of TextEdit to Cell in GridView. How to Complete my Task ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your [GridControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridGridControltopic) has a [GridView](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridViewtopic) called `view`, it could look like this:

```
var editvalue = txtEdit.EditValue;
GridColumn myColumn = //your column
int rowHandle = //your rowhandle

view.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, myColumn, editvalue);
```

Also - you should see the online documentation for [`SetRowCellValue`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_SetRowCellValuetopic1169)

Comment: Hi Jens, am getting error on mycolumn "Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method" ?

Comment: show me (by editing you question) the code that is the problem :)

Comment: I Solved that but still error I dono exactly what to write on "rowhandle" I want to fire this code when i get value in the textedit ?

Comment: I edit like this but nothing change in run time `for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                var editvalue = textEdit12.Text;
                GridColumn myColumn = gridView1.Columns["forignkey"];
                int rowHandle = i; 

                gridView1.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, myColumn, editvalue);
            }`

Comment: hmm [read the remarks](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_SetRowCellValuetopic1169), perhaps that is why nothing happens :) the RowHandle is an integer that reperesent each row in the gridview. I think it might start at 1 not 0.